# PyQt5 - Getting information from a QcomboBox on TableWidget

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm looking for some piece of code that enables me to get the information of a combobox that I've put it on a TableView created by QtDesigner.

For lack of knowledge I'm not using any classes or Delegates. When I was using TableWidget the line `TableWidget.cellWidget(indexofthecurrentrow, 4).currentIndex() == 0` returned me the current status of the row allowing me to update the database, but that line doesn't work on TableView I'm assuming because of the model or absence of a Delegate.

Relevant Code Below:

```
for row in range(len(data_from_sqlite)):
      comboBox = QComboBox()
      comboBox.addItems('opt1', 'opt2')
      index_combo = tableview.model().index(row, 5) 
      tableview.setIndexWidget(index_combo, comboBox)
```

I just don't know how to retrieve this QComboBox state through other function connected in a button.
I've tried both

```
tableview.model().index(0,4).itemData().currentIndex() #crashes
```

and

```
tableview.model().index(0,4).data() #returns None
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to a my problem and as pointed by musicamante the solution involves using classes witch is very basic and was very difficult for me.

The loop that implements the combobox in the tableview is:

```
for row in range(len(data)):
    combo = combomaker(self)
    index_combo = self.tableview.model().index(row, 5)
    self.tableview.setIndexWidget(index_combo, combo)
```

being the combo maker as it follows

```
class combo(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.addItems(['a', 'b'])
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.getComboValue)

    def getComboValue(self):
        print(self.currentText())
        # return self.currentText()
```

I took the code from Jie Jenn https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMJTJNUzo4E

Hope this help some clueless programmer in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using cell widgets makes absolutely *no* interaction with the table's model and its data.

If you need to access a specific cell widget, use the *getter* function opposite to `setIndexWidget()`, [`indexWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexWidget):

```
combo = tableview.indexWidget(tableview.model().index(0,4))
combo_index = combo.currentIndex()
```

Comment: I did not understand what those lines should do exactly. I'm trying to use another def to access the data inside the combobox that is on the tableview, but when I run those lines in that other def the program crashes. Here's the full code: https://pastebin.com/QNH3U4Yj

Comment: Now I get it when you said that you are "not using any classes". Unfortunately, using Qt like that is highly unsuggested, it only makes things much more complex than they could. Try to understand what my code does and read the related documentation. Then I strongly suggest you to study how classes work and try to get experience, because without that knowledge you won't go very far with almost any language or framework, and with systems like Python or Qt not only you'll have only more difficulties, but people will unlikely be able to really help you.